# offset() y position() - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema.

En Firefox, al usar la propiedad `.position()`, esta siempre es relativa a la posición de la ventana del navegador, es decir, hace que la posición de la ventana nunca llegue a la posición del elemento, porque se va incrementando la posición `top` dicho elemento. En cambio, con Chrome esto pasa.

Pensé en usar la propiedad `.offset()`, pero esta no me obtiene la posición real del elemento (no obtiene los márgenes, por lo que siempre está por debajo de la posición real).

```
var menu;
var windowPosition = 0;

/* Secciones donde el menú debe ser negro */
var box1;
var box1Inicio = 0;
var box1Fin = 0;

var imgMenu;

$(window).load(function() {
    menu = $(".menu");
    if( $("#box-text-1").length ) {
        box1 = $("#box-text-1");
        box1Inicio = box1.offset().top; //Aquí es donde probé ambos métodos
        box1Fin = box1Inicio + box1.outerHeight(true);
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    windowPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    if( windowPosition >= box1Inicio && windowPosition <= box1Fin ) {
        imgMenu = menu.find(".menu-button").find("img").attr("data-black");
    }
    else {
        imgMenu = menu.find(".menu-button").find("img").attr("data-white");
    }
    menu.find(".menu-button img").attr("src", imgMenu);
});
```

Esté código básicamente comprueba la posición top del navegador, y si se encuentra entre esos "inicio" y "fin", cambia la imagen del menú.

El HTML sería algo parecido a esto:

```
<div class="seccion1">
    ...
</div>
<div class="seccion2" id="box-text-1">
    ...
</div>
<div class="seccion3">
    ...
</div>
```

Cada sección con sus `padding`'s y `margin`s. Como mencioné arriba, la propiedad `offset()` no me obtiene estos atributos, pero con `position()` en Firefox siempre me está cambiando los valores de `top`.

¿Alguna solución que pueda aplicar a este problema?

Edito: [Añado JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjjpqkm1/)

Comment: ¿Podrías [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: en realidad `position` es relativo al padre y `offset` relativo al documento. Puede haber cierta diferencia entre los valores de los navegadores pero en principio los metodos funcionan igual. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo funcionando?

Comment: @blonfu lo se, pero con FireFox, el top no para de incrementarse. Añadido, el jsfiddle, si introduzco `offset` en el jsfiddle me sale el error `undefined`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo jsfiddle añadido

Comment: Puede que haya encontrado el problema, y sería introducir el `$(window).scroll()` dentro de `$(window).load()`. De esta manera parece funcionar.

Comment: @Cheshire, por favor, agrega el código dentro de tu pregunta. El botón [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/36618/edit) esta justo debajo de los `tags`

Comment: pues a mi me funciona igual en Firefox y Chrome. ¿Has cambiado algo en el jsfiddle?

Comment: @blonfu en absoluto, es lo mismo que tengo en local

Comment: Quá raro. Bueno, veo que lo has solucionado ya de todas formas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El error es que en `Firefox` al hacer scroll no se ejecuta la función que modifica el `src` de la imagen.

Intenta hacer la siguiente modificación.

Reemplaza esto:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
```

Por esto:

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
```

Comment: Parece ser que así también funciona, gracias. También puse el scroll dentro del `$(window).load()` y también me funciona de este modo, tal vez estaba intentando hacer algo antes de que estuviera cargado.